# Problem with wrapping text in Multirow!

Tags: tables, multirow, wrap

I am really struggling to make a simple table. But my problem is that the dear LaTeX doesn't wrap my text in one column which has a multirow. I have made a photo out of the main pdf which indicates everything.
My code is:

[image]

```
\begin{table}
\caption[Information modules of EPD]{Information modules within any of the life cycle stages are communicated depending on the types of EPD.}
\label{tab:InfoModu}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.15\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}}
\toprule
\tabhead{Information modules} & \tabhead{Description} & \tabhead{Explanation} \\
\midrule
A1 & Raw material extraction and processing, processing of secondary material input (e.g. recycling processes) & $\multirow{3}{*}{Product stage: including provision of\\ all materials, products and energy,\\ as well as waste processing up to the end-of waste state or disposal of final residues \\during the product stage. Module A1, A2 and A3 may\\ be declared as one aggregated module A1-3.}$\\
A2 & Transport to the manufacturer  & ~\\
A3 & Manufacturing & ~\\
\hline

A4 & Transport to the building site & $\multirow{2}{*}{Construction process stage: including provision of all materials, products and energy, as well as waste processing up to the end-of- waste state or disposal of final residues during the construction process stage. These information modules also include all impacts and aspects related to any losses during this construction process stage (i.e. production, transport, and waste processing and disposal of the lost products and materials).}$\\
A5 & Installation into the building & ~\\
\hline

B1 & Use or application of the installed product & $\multirow{5}{*}{Use stage, related to the building fabric: including provision and transport of all materials, products and related energy and water use, as well as waste processing up to the end-of-waste state or disposal of final residues during this part of the use stage. These information modules also include all impacts and aspects related to the losses during this part of the use stage (i.e. production, transport, and waste processing and disposal of the lost products and materials).}$\\
B2 & Maintenance & ~\\
B3 & Repair & ~\\
B4 & Replacement & ~\\
B5 & Refurbishment & ~\\
\hline

B6 & Operational energy use (HVAC) & $\multirow{2}{*}{Use stage related to the operation of the building: These information modules include provision and transport of all materials, products, as well as energy and water provisions, waste processing up to the end-of-waste state or disposal of final residues during this part of the use stage.}$\\
B7 & Operational water use & ~\\
\hline

C1 & De-construction, demolition & $\multirow{4}{*}{End-of-life stage: including provision and all transport, provision of all materials, products and related energy and water}$\\
C2 & Transport to waste processing & ~\\
C3 & Waste processing for reuse, recovery and/or recycling & ~\\
C4 & Disposal & ~\\
\hline

D & Reuse, recovery and/or recycling potentials, expressed as net impacts and benefits & Benefits and loads beyond the system boundary \\
\bottomrule\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would be very happy if somebody could help me with it.

Thnx a lot
Pouya

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! In your \multirows, replace the `{*}` argument with `{=}` since you have fixed width columns.

Comment: Also, remove all `$` around the `\multirow` commands as well as the `\\ ` inside of `\multirow`. You will also have to adapt the first argument of each `\multirow` command. This number refers to the lines of text, not table rows. While the first `\multirow` indeed spans 3 table rows, it also spans 6 lines of text, so `\multirow{6}{=}` would be correct here. Adapt the other commands accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document with your table, which start with `\documentclass[...]{...}` and end with `\end{document}`. So far we can only guess about your document design.

Your table have more issues (see comments below question). Beside them you have problems with overlapping of multirow text. This you can prevent with adding empty rows in table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption[Information modules of EPD]
        {Information modules within any of the life cycle stages are communicated depending on the types of EPD.}
\label{tab:InfoModu}
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X
                                   >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}X @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{Inf.\\ mod.} & \thead{Description} & \thead{Explanation} \\
    \midrule
A1  &   Raw material extraction and processing, processing of secondary material input (e.g. recycling processes) 
        &   \multirow[t]{5}{=}{Product stage: including provision of all materials, products and energy, as well as waste processing up to the end-of waste state or disposal of final residues during the product stage. Module A1, A2 and A3 may be declared as one aggregated module A1-3.}                           \\
A2  & Transport to the manufacturer     &       \\
A3  & Manufacturing                     &       \\
    \midrule
A4  & Transport to the building site 
        &   \multirow[t]{7}{=}{Construction process stage: including provision of all materials, products and energy, as well as waste processing up to the end-of- waste state or disposal of final residues during the construction process stage. These information modules also include all impacts and aspects related to any losses during this construction process stage (i.e. production, transport, and waste processing and disposal of the lost products and materials).}   \\
A5  & Installation into the building    &       \\
    &                                   &       \\
    &                                   &       \\
    &                                   &       \\
    \addlinespace
    \midrule
B1  &   Use or application of the installed product 
        &   \multirow[t]{5}{=}{Use stage, related to the building fabric: including provision and transport of all materials, products and related energy and water use, as well as waste processing up to the end-of-waste state or disposal of final residues during this part of the use stage. These information modules also include all impacts and aspects related to the losses during this part of the use stage (i.e. production, transport, and waste processing and disposal of the lost products and materials).}   \\
B2  &   Maintenance                     &       \\
B3  & Repair                            &       \\
B4  & Replacement                       &       \\
B5  & Refurbishment                     &       \\
    \addlinespace
    \midrule
B6  & Operational energy use (HVAC) 
        &   \multirow[t]{2}{=}{Use stage related to the operation of the building: These information modules include provision and transport of all materials, products, as well as energy and water provisions, waste processing up to the end-of-waste state or disposal of final residues during this part of the use stage.}    \\
B7  &   Operational water use           &       \\
    &                                   &       \\
    &                                   &       \\
    \midrule
C1  &   De-construction, demolition 
        &   \multirow[t]{2}{=}{End-of-life stage: including provision and all transport, provision of all materials, products and related energy and water}\\
C2  &   Transport to waste processing   &       \\
C3  &   Waste processing for reuse, recovery and/or recycling 
                                        &       \\
C4  & Disposal                          &       \\
    \midrule
D   & Reuse, recovery and/or recycling potentials, expressed as net impacts and benefits 
        & Benefits and loads beyond the system boundary \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did it your way with some more empty lines and it worked however it's not centred but fine. ;)

Comment: @PouyaMahdavi, what is not centered? Table has now profesional looks (at least in my opinion, see for reference https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/. You could accept answer :-)